# PHP Namespaces strange behaviour. Calling PDO method and __autoload is trigerred again?

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces, autoload

I've following class and initPDO fails after adding setAttribute

```
namespace DBInterface;
class DBInterface {
    protected function initPDO() {
       $dsn = sprintf('sqlsrv:Server=%s;Database=%s', DB_SQL_SERVERNAME, DB_DB_NAME);
       $this->obPDO = new \PDO($dsn, DB_SQL_USERNAME, DB_SQL_PASSWORD);     
       $this->obPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

Which gives PHP error:

```
Could not find class file: DBInterface/PDO in root lib directory nor build lib path
Trace: [file] => path\lib\DBInterface\DBInterface.php
        [line] => 23
        [function] => __autoload
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => DBInterface\PDO
            )
```

Do you see something stupid? I can not figure it out oO.
Line 23 points at setAttribute method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a namespace issue. `PDO` exists in the root namespace, so you need a backslash at the beginning of your constants. Just like you do with `new \PDO`.

```
$this->obPDO->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Without the backslashes, PHP is looking for `PDO` inside your `DBInterface` namespace. As you can see in the error, it's look for `DBInterface\PDO` which doesn't exist.

Comment: You could also use 'use PDO;' to "import" the class into the current namespace.

Comment: That was really stupid.
I've wrongly assumed that this was a constant so I did not add the /.